# When should I answer my own question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Hi there.

I have created a question in Stackoverflow. A user pointed out that there are a lot of similar questions, suggesting to read their answers and then update my question. It is possible that none of them have the (whole) answer I need. It is possible that the intersection of that answers can be the answer to my question (1), or not (2).

What should I do? I think best way is to update my question writing why that questions are not useful when (2) happens. If (1), should I answer my own question, or should I delete the question (leaving the question could lead to a partial duplicate)?

Thanks.
—Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of (1), I think you should answer your own question. Otherwise every other person, with the same problem/question as you, will also need to read all other questions/answers, instead of just reading your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel that you can compose an answer that will match your question and that your question is original (not an exact duplicate of some other question), then you can answer yourself and accept this answer.

If you think that your question is a duplicate of some other question (which already has an answer), you can delete your own question and add a [possibly better] answer to that other question.